# Amplify - GraphQL request headers are empty

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, graphql

I am attempting to create an app that utilizes Cognito user pools for user auth and then sending api requests to a dynamoDB table through graphQL.
The user auth/signup works correctly, however I receive a 401 error when attempting to query a data table. The message states "Missing authorization header"
I saw in a similar post that the auth token should be auto-populated into the request headers, but that does not occur for me. I also saw that Amplify created a function for custom graphql headers. I attempted this also but still get the same "Missing authorization header" error. 
Any suggestions?

```
        aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint:'',
        aws_appsync_region:'',
        aws_appsync_authenticationType:'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS',

        graphql_headers: async () => ({
            'My-Custom-Header': cognitoUser
        })
    }
```

This is in my config/exports file for amplify ---- Amplify.configure(config)

````
  if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else if (!session.isValid()) {
        console.log("Invalid session.");
      } else {
        console.log( session.getIdToken().getJwtToken());
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log("User not found.");
  }
  console.log(cognitoUser)

Amplify.configure(config)

const client = new AWSAppSyncClient({
    disableOffline: true,
    url: config.aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint,
    region: config.aws_appsync_region,
    identityPoolId: config.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
    userPoolId: config.aws_user_pools_id,
    userPoolWebClientId: config.ws_user_pools_web_client_id,
    auth: {
        type: config.aws_appsync_authenticationType,
        jwtoken: async () =>
        (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken(),
        apiKey: config.aws_appsync_apiKey
    }
});```

This is my client settings in my index.js folder

I apologize if I missed something blatant. I am new to backend and am having trouble with getting this to work. 
I have only gotten it to work when using API_Key auth.
````